# Posting String To Web Server, Get Response

Tags: c++, objective-c, httprequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

I have a long base64 encoded text string. It's about 1024 characters. From my Objective C code, I want to send it to my PHP script, have it dump it to a log, and return an "OK" response back. I tried [this cookbook example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/67081/cookbook-using-nsurlsession), but it only has an example of upload and download (not both combined), and it doesn't even work in my case.

I'd be willing to switch this to a C++ solution if I knew how.

## The Objective C Client Code (command line client)

```
NSString *sMessage = @"My Long Base64 Encoded Message";
NSString *sURL = "http://example.com/request.php";
NSURL *oURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sURL];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:sMessage.UTF8String length:sMessage.length];

NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
  dataTaskWithURL:oURL completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"\n\nDATA\n\n%@",data);
    NSLog(@"\n\nRESPONSE\n\n%@",response);
    NSLog(@"\n\nERROR\n\n%@",error);

}];

[downloadTask resume];
```

## The PHP Web Server Code

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
$sRaw = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('TEST.TXT',$sRaw);
die('OK');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a far easier route using ordinary C++. You'll have to convert your .m file to a .mm file in order to be able to mix Objective C and C++ code.

The PHP code is good and doesn't require a revision. Here's the C++ example I used that worked. It used the STL and curl. I was doing this on a Mac, and by default OSX has the curl libraries pre-installed. Note that the example below is synchronous -- it jams program execution until the server call is completed. (I desired this in my case -- you may not.)

## The C++ Client Code (class)

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

class Webby {

public:

static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream) {
    std::string buf = std::string(static_cast<char *>(ptr), size * nmemb);
    std::stringstream *response = static_cast<std::stringstream *>(stream);
    response->write(buf.c_str(), (std::streamsize)buf.size());
    return size * nmemb;
}

static std::string sendRawHTTP(std::string sHostURL, std::string &sStringData) {

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        std::stringstream response;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, sHostURL.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sStringData.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, Webby::write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        return response.str();
    }
    return "";
}

}; // end class
```